# Wrong behavior with flag ios_base::app

Tags: c++, sstream

As far as I know the flag `app` seeks to the end before each write
[const ios_base::openmode std::ios_base::app [static]
    Seek to end before each write.](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/532/d2af84ebd02e42d29ba30f9.png)

the following program output is: `recostream789`

```
std::string str("t2: 123456789");
std::ostringstream ostr(str,std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::app);
ostr << "recostream";
std::cout << ostr.str() << std::endl;
```

shouldn't it output: `t2: 123456789recostream` instead?

I'm using vs2010

[Compiled code image](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/532/d2af84ebd02e42d29ba30f9.png)

Comment: It works for me as expected, but that is using GCC 4.7.

Comment: oh didn't see that, i was `using namespace std` though, without it and `std::` qualifier it is still the same output, also edited the question

Comment: Yep I saw the update. I have modified my comment too. There doesn't really seem to be an explanation for the strange behaviour.

Comment: Same (incorrect) behavior on VS2012 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is open defect [LWG #2121](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#2121), opened by Josuttis earlier this year. His report uses GCC and Visual Studio as the examples as well, to quote:

> Note the following program:

```
string s("s1: 123456789");
ostringstream s1(s, ios_base::out|ios_base::app);
s1 << "hello";
cout << s1.str() << endl;
```

> With g++4.x it prints:
>
> `s1: 123456789hello`
>
> With VisualC++10 it prints:
>
> `hello23456789`

Mote that the behavior of the flag `ios_base::ate` was not explicitly specified for stringstreams in C++03, but C++11 [added](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-defects.html#1448) detailed stringstream-specific effects for it. It didn't add such details for `ios_base::app`, so some compilers didn't bother implementing it.

Comment: +1 for the references, the defect goes way deeper from what I've read

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it should -- at least to me this looks like a compiler (or, technically, library) bug.

Doing a quick check, g++ (4.7.1) seems to agree -- it produces `t2: 123456789recostream` as expected.

Comment: Note [this bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/692248) which claims microsoft is correct.

Comment: @JesseGood: I'll send STL an email -- I see nothing there that says that §27.5.3.1.4/1: `app    seek to end before each write` should be ignored.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: What about `if mode & ios_base::ate is true, pptr() == pbase() + s.size() holds, otherwise pptr() == pbase() is true`, the `otherwise pptr() == pbase()` part seems to say the current position should be pointing at the beginning **unless** `ios_base::ate` is used.

Comment: @JesseGood: I had written another comment in reply, but looking at Cubbi's answer, it appears it's already been reported as a bug to the committee. I still think gcc has it right and VC++ has it wrong though. With `ios_base::app` specified, the put pointer should be positioned to the beginning at construction, but to the end immediately before a write. I see no real conflict or lack of clarity here.

Comment: Yes, intuitively, gcc has it right although the current wording in the standard is insufficient (and it seems P.J. Plauger is against it although I didn't understand the reasoning).